# Delete Folder and contents with contains specific name

Tags: batch-file

I would like to delete the folder and it contents when it contains a specific string in its folder name.

For example,

```
C:\Documents\System_This_Computer_08-01-Mon_1416
C:\Documents\System_This_Computer_09-01-Tue_1120
C:\Documents\System_This_Computer_10-01-Wed_2315
C:\Documents\System_This_Computer_11-01-Thu_0816
C:\Documents\MyDocus
C:\Documents\ToPrintout
```

With the above folders, i want to delete the folder which contains strings like System_This_Computer.

So, the output should be,

```
C:\Documents\MyDocus
C:\Documents\ToPrintout
```

should only be available. remaining should be deleted.

May I know how to do this?

Comment: `for /d %a in (*System_This_Computer*) do rd /s /q %a`. For use in a batchfile, replace every `%a` with `%%a`.

Comment: May i know how to add the time delayed delete. like delete folder which was created more than 10 days old

Comment: You could enter `ForFiles /?` at the Command prompt for it's help information!

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48262597/edit) your code into the question to make it readable (and make your question on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, the following should show you all of the directories in `C:\Documents` which have names beginning with `System_This_Computer` and have not been modified in the last `10` days.

```bat
ForFiles /P "C:\Documents" /M "System_This_Computer*" /D -10 /C "Cmd /C If @isdir==TRUE Echo @path"
```

Once you are satisfied with the output, change `Echo` to `RD /S/Q` to actually remove them.